# Angular 2 - PrimeNG Mock Datatable Selection

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

How do I mock data to be chosen in PrimeNG's datatable?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'p-dataTable',
    template: `...`
})
class MockDataTableComponent {
    @Input() value;
    @Input() selection;
    @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();
    click( rows: number) {
        this.selection = rows;
        return this.selection;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'data-table',
    template: `<p-dataTable #datatable></p-dataTable>`
})
class MyTableComponent {
    @ViewChild('datatable') datatable;
}
```

How do I manually set a values to the mocked selection in PrimeNG? I want to assign a value to selection like

```
this.selection[0]['name'] = "John Doe";
this.selection[0]['age'] = 30;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your initial selection into `<p-dataTable>`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'p-dataTable',
    template: `...`
})
class MockDataTableComponent {
    @Input() value;
    @Input() selection;
    @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();
    click( rows: number) {
        this.selection = rows;
        return this.selection;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'data-table',
    template: `<p-dataTable [selection]="mockSelection" #datatable></p-dataTable>`
})
class MyTableComponent {

    mockSelection = [];

    constructor(){
        this.mockSelection[0]={};
        this.mockSelection[0]['name'] = "John Doe";
        this.mockSelection[0]['age'] = 30;
    }
    @ViewChild('datatable') datatable;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I actually transferred the setting of the selection to the MockDataTableComponent. Thanks.